# "//"-prefixed JSON return giving inconsistent results

Tags: json, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I have a cfc function which is called via ajax. It accepts a merchant code (either a single code or comma-delimited list of codes), performs some checks and I/O, then returns a flag.

**NOTE:
We have enabled the CFAdmin setting "prefix JSON with '//'" enabled for security reasons, which seems to be the root of the problem here.**

**CFC FUNCTION:**

There are only two possible returns from this function: A string (e.g. "qweqweqwe"), or "1".

The string is returned within the loop when an invalid `merchant_code` is encountered.
"1" is returned after the loop as an indication of success of the entire process.

```
<cffunction name="createCategoryMerchant" access="remote" returntype="any" returnFormat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="category_id" required="true" type="numeric"/>
    <cfargument name="merchant_code" required="true" type="any" default="" hint="expect list of merchant codes"/>
    <cfset var qChk = 0 />
    <cfset var qIns = 0 />
    <cfset var vItem = "">
    
    <cfloop list="#arguments.merchant_code#" index="item">
        
        <!--- does merchant exist? --->
        <cfquery name="qChk" datasource="#DSN#"> 
            select id from merchant
            where merchant_num = <cfqueryparam value="#item#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
        </cfquery>

        <cfif not qChk.recordcount>
            <cfreturn merchant_code> <!--- return bad code, e.g. "qweqweqwe" --->
            <cfbreak>
        </cfif>

        <!--- Has the merchant already been assigned to this category? --->
        <cfquery name="qChk" datasource="#DSN#"> 
            select unique_id 
            from category_merchant
            where category_id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.category_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
            and merchant_code = <cfqueryparam value="#item#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
        </cfquery>

        <cfif qChk.recordcount>
            <cfcontinue> <!--- silently accept and bail out, even though already exists --->
        </cfif>
        
        <!--- insert record if code is legit --->
        <cfquery name="qIns" datasource="#DSN#"> 
            insert into category_merchant (category_id, merchant_code)
            values (
                <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.category_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />,
                <cfqueryparam value="#UCASE(item)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
                )
        </cfquery>

    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn 1>
</cffunction>
```

**AJAX:**

In the code below, I have included two different ajax call options which I have tried, and each produces different results as noted in the code comments.

```
$('.btnAddMerchant').on('click',function(e){
    
    var clickedID = $(this).attr("id");
    var category_id = clickedID.split("_")[1];
    var merchant_code = $('#merchant_code').val();
    merchant_code = merchant_code.replace(/\s/g,'');
    $('.res').empty().hide;

    if(merchant_code.length == 0){
        $('#resAdd').show().html('Enter merchant code');
    }else{

        // OPTION 1: Note I have used "dataFilter" to handle the "//" prefixed JSON

        $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url: '/system.cfc?method=createCategoryMerchant',
              data: {category_id:category_id,merchant_code:merchant_code},
              dataFilter: function(data, type) {return data.substr(2)},
              dataType: 'json',
              cache:false,
              success: function(res) {
                  alert(res);  // This only fires for INVALID codes, i.e. if the cfc returns a string such as "qweqweqwe". Doesn't fire for a single numeric return, e.g. "1"                
              }
         });
        
        // OPTION  2:           

        $.getJSON("/system.cfc?method=createCategoryMerchant&returnformat=json",{"category_id":category_id,"merchant_code":merchant_code},function(res,code){
            alert(res); // This only fires if the code is VALID, i.e. the CFC returns "1". It does not fire if the invalid code "qweqweqwe" is returned
        });
                    
    }
});
```

NOTE ALSO: Only the invalid code returns with the "//" prefix. If a "1" is return, this is not prefixed.

[image]

If I disable the CFAdmin setting "prefix JSON with '//'", then all the problems disappear.
I would prefer to use ajax option 1 above, but need to know why it apparently just silently fails to process the returned flag "1" for valid data.

**EDIT**

The problem may simply be that the dataFilter attribute in option 1 is working with a returned value that is not prefixed by "//". Then why is it that the "1" is not returned with the "//" prefix, whereas "qweqweqw" DOES have the prefix?

Comment: Tbh, I am surprised it works at all since neither is actually valid json. I'd guess CF just uses a simple algorithm like, is the result a string and the return format json. It probably sees the 1 as a number and skips it. Anyway, it'd probably work consistently if the function returned a valid json struct/string instead of a simple value.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this using:

```
<cfreturn serializeJSON(1)>
```

This seems to manually add the "//" prefix to the "1". Not sure why it was absent in the first place.